# using tablib and django-import-export to import data, getting error with excel, but with csv it's working

Tags: python, django, python-import, django-import-export, tablib

At first trying to read excel/csv data to check it before inserting into database, 
While csv working fine can read data, but xlsx and xlx showing following error

> UnicodeDecodeError at /academy/add_advisor
>   'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 10: invalid start byte

Snippet of my code:

```
from tablib import Dataset
this_file = request.FILES['bulk_file']

dataset = Dataset()
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().decode("utf-8"),format='xlsx')

for data in dataset:
    print(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
```

According to error message error coming from this line

```
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().decode("utf-8"),format='xlsx')
```

The excel file i am trying to import, i downloaded it from google drive excel as xlsx file(microsoft excel). Also downloaded one from onedrive(microsoft) xlsx file still getting same error.

Few more ways i have tried with are

```
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().decode("ISO-8859-1"),format='xlsx')
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().strip().decode("ISO-8859-1"),format='xlsx')
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().strip().decode("CP1252"),format='xlsx')
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().strip().decode("windows-1252"),format='xlsx')
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read().strip().decode("Latin-1"),format='xlsx')
```

But no luck :(
Please share if there has any better way i can try :)(:
Thank you for read :)

Comment: It looks to me that it looks for a stream, not for a string, what if you only usee `load(the_file, format='xlsx')`?

Comment: Hi, tnx for you reply, 
Actually if you check load is a method of dataset, using that to load the data from excel to dataset object . After that will loop with dataset object(variable) to get each line of data

Comment: yes but the documentation (http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/api/#tablib.Dataset.load) specifies an `in_stream`. A file handler is a stream: you can use it for example to binary read it. So you only need to pass the file handler I think. Or perhaps a binary string, but decoding makes no sense, since an `.xlsx` is actually a zipped collection of XML files.

Comment: looks like after removing .decode("utf-8") it works.

Comment: Yes it is working,

Comment: please give an answer below i want to accept this answer. Was working from last 7+ hrs on it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your `the_file` is an `.xlsx` file, then it is probably no good idea to *decode* the stream manually: an `.xlsx` is a *zipped* stream of XML files. So that means it does not really follow a standard string encoding.

But the [**`dataset.load(..)`**](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/api/#tablib.Dataset.load) also suggests it does not per see needs a string, it needs data that it aims to load. In case of an `.xlsx` file, that is *binary* data, so we can use `.read()` to read the content of the file into a binary string, and thus let the `dataset` do the correct processing, like:

```
imported_data = dataset.load(this_file.read(),format='xlsx')
```